# Missing dependency warning while running a React 16 application using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below is a sample React 16 useEffect code

```
  useEffect(() => {
   const var3 = var1  + var2;
  }, [var1]);
```

I want above effect to be called only when **var1** changes but inside that effect I am using **var2** so I am getting the warning missing dependency **var2**. I don't want the effect to be called when **var2** changes.

I want to resolve the warning without injecting the **var2** inside the **dependency array**.

Any help or input will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You can disable this eslint

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this, it explains how to use useEffect safely

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies